# __setitem__ не видит действий вложенных словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, словари, dict

```
from collections import UserDict


class Matching(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(key, value)
        super(Matching, self).__setitem__(key, value)


def main():
    m = Matching({"user": "milkiweed", "settings": {"notifications": True, "online": False}})
    m["settings"]["notifications"] = False
```

Ошибка заключается в следующем:

При инициализации класса метод `__setitem__` отрабатывает корректно и мне отображаются все ключи и их значения, НО, последующий вызов (см. последнюю строку кода) должен тоже триггерить этот метод, однако никакие принты не вылазят на экран, хотя значение изменяется вполне себе корректно.

Как можно зафиксировать именно момент изменения ключа? Почему данное явление случается лишь в кейсе с вложенными словарями, т.к если провести аналогичную операцию без учета вложенности, все выполняется корректно и я получаю оповещения об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
obj[i][j] = x
```

приблизительно соответствует вызову

```py
obj.__getitem__(i).__setitem__(j, x)
```

т.е. при присваивании вложенному ключу вообще не происходит вызова `__setitem__` вышестоящего объекта.

Чтобы контролировать процесс, `__getitem__` должен возвращать не сам словарь, а какую-нибудь хитрую обертку.

```py
from functools import partial

class Nested:
    def __init__(self, cb):
        self.cb = cb

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Nested(partial(self.cb, key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.cb(key, value)

obj = Nested(print)
obj['a']['b']['c'] = 1 # будет вызвано print('a', 'b', 'c', 1)
```

Правда этот пример работает только на присваивание, но довести до ума его можно.

Также можно работать с ключами-кортежами, для этого даже не придется переписывать логику чтения/записи данных.

```py
a = {}
a['key1'] = 'val1'
a['key1', 'key2'] = 'val2'
a['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] = 'val3'
print(a) # {'key1': 'val1', ('key1', 'key2'): 'val2', ('key1', 'key2', 'key3'): 'val3'}
```

Правда изменится семантика, и обход в глубину усложнится.